# how many groups can be made from numbers based on range parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have to do this task and I can't find out how to do it.

> A number belongs to an existing cluster (joins it) if its distance to at least one number already in the cluster is not greater than the preconfigured spacing.
> If the new number (data point) does not belong to any already identified cluster, it becomes a new one.
> New number that lands between two nearby clusters may belong to both of them, thus merging them into one.
>
> correct example:
>
> `[100, 0, 7, -89, 80, 86, -100, 2, 81]`
>
> return 5 clusters

I have made this but it works only if numbers are input in ascending order:

```
accept = (value: number): void => {
    if (this.previous == undefined || Math.abs((this.previous) - value) > this.spacing) {
        this.counter++;
    }
    this.previous = value;
}
```

I have to input data one by one because tests looks like this:

```
it("mine spacing 2", () => {
    detector.accept(4);
    detector.accept(7);
    expect(detector.clusterCount()).toEqual(2);
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your example a little bit more? I don't take it to be the expected input, which if the case, what is? If its the output, what's the input?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please note the formatting I've done in your question. It's important to identify what parts are quoted and what parts aren't. Please also use correct punctuation and capitalization, for clarity.

Comment: The code you say you've tried is obviously part of something a bit larger. Please show your full code, not just a small part of it, but be sure that you've turned it into a [mcve] first.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, Sorry I'll try to put everything here now.

I have to modify accept method. I think whether or not to make an array that I would sort each time and check if it falls within the range for the previous and next number after placing it in the array. But I can't write it yet.

```
export class MyLinearClusterDetectorFactory implements LinearClusterDetectorFactory {
create(spacing: number): LinearClusterDetector {
    return new MyLinearClusterDetector(spacing);
}

class MyLinearClusterDetector implements LinearClusterDetector {
constructor(readonly spacing: number) {
}
counter = 0;
previous: number | undefined;
accept = (value: number): void => {
    if (this.previous == undefined || Math.abs((this.previous) - value) > this.spacing) {
        this.counter++;
        
    }
    this.previous = value;
}
clusterCount = (): number => {
    return this.counter;
}
```

}

And i have tests already written :

```
describe("Basic testing with spacing 2", () => {
let detector: LinearClusterDetector;
beforeEach(() => {
    detector = new MyLinearClusterDetectorFactory().create(2);
});

it("returns 0 if never called", () => {
    expect(detector.clusterCount()).toEqual(0);
});

it("returns 1 if called once", () => {
    detector.accept(1);
    expect(detector.clusterCount()).toEqual(1);
});

it("returns 1 if called with overlapping", () => {
    detector.accept(1);
    detector.accept(2);
    expect(detector.clusterCount()).toEqual(1);
});

it("returns 2 if called with evidently non-overlapping", () => {
    detector.accept(1);
    detector.accept(4);
    expect(detector.clusterCount()).toEqual(2);
});
it("mine spacing 2", () => {
    detector.accept(4);
    detector.accept(7);
    expect(detector.clusterCount()).toEqual(2);
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You could collect combined arrays and return finally the longest count.

```js
const
    getMaxClusterSize = (array, space) => {
        return array
            .reduce((r, v) => {
                const [temp, filtered] = r.reduce((q, a) => {
                    q[+a.some(w => Math.abs(v - w) <= space)].push(a);
                    return q;
                }, [[], []]);

                temp.push(filtered.length
                    ? [...filtered.flat(), v]
                    : [v]
                );
                return temp;
            }, [])
            // .reduce((a, b) => a.length > b.length ? a : b)
            // .length; 
    };
    

console.log(getMaxClusterSize([100, 0, 7, -89, 80, 86, -100, 2, 81], 15)); // 4
```

Comment: Works great, thank you very much. But I'm not on that level to understand it yet. I'll try to do it in a simpler and more accessible way for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should have been a comment, but I have not enough stack-points to make them.
have a look a this wikipedia article if you want state of the art solution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure